# Not Attached, <Window null#winPop>

Tags: java, zk

I have a problem with my code using zk components.
I am trying to make a popup window without zul file but compose it within my java code.

This is the sample of the code of mine

```
@Listen("onClick = #btnPopUp")public void popUp(){
 Window win = new Window();
 win.setId("winPop");
 /* i compose some rows, label and other component here...*/

 win.doModal();

}
```

When i click the `btnPopUp` button, i got an error message `ERROR org.zkoss - >> org.zkoss.zk.ui.SuspendNotAllowedException: Not attached, <Window null#winPop>`

I got a clue to use `Executions.createComponents()` method. But is this method can really help? because i usually use this method with a zul file for ex: `Window win = (Window) Executions.createComponents("myZul",parent, map);`

Thanks guys, really appreciate your help
//Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Not attached‘ is ZK's way of saying the component (the ‘Window‘) doesn't have a parent component.

```
win.setParent(parent);
```

or

```
parent.appendChild(win);
```

I believe this needs to be done before ‘win.doModal()‘ is called.

Comment: what is the class name of `parent` object?

Comment: [Refer to the JavaDocs](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/AbstractComponent.html#setParent(org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component)).

Comment: i've got this one guys :D i realize that getself().getparent() return the parent of this windows.